# Binary not accessible from Bash despite being in path

Tags: bash, quoting, filenames, path

I am learning how to program in Racket. Its binary is in `"/Applications/Racket v6.2/bin/racket"`.

Let me show what happens:

```
MacBook:~ enedil$ echo $PATH
/Applications/Racket\ v6.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
MacBook:~ enedil$ ls -l /Applications/Racket\ v6.2/bin/racket
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 enedil  admin  53712 Jun 19 22:23 /Applications/Racket v6.2/bin/racket
MacBook:~ enedil$ file /Applications/Racket\ v6.2/bin/racket
/Applications/Racket v6.2/bin/racket: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
MacBook:~ enedil$ racket
-bash: racket: command not found
MacBook:~ enedil$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

How is this ever possible? What to do if I want a fully-working Racket compiler in my path?

Comment: Check the extended attribute on `racket`.

Comment: @fd0 empty output.

Comment: @cuonglm I edited the question.

Comment: Apologies, I tought the following `/bin` was meant to be the `/bin` path.

Comment: @enedil The file has an extended attribute. Try `xattr -l /Applications/Racket\ v6.2/bin/racket`

Comment: You messed up the `PATH`. Try `PATH="/Applications/Racket v6.2/bin:$PATH"; export PATH` then try again.

Comment: @fd0 still nothing. There was one (`com.apple.quarantine`) which I deleted - it is used to prevent malware on OS X.

Comment: @cuonglm thanks alot! So, no escape sequences before spaces in PATH. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it pleasely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have made a mistake when editing `PATH` variable. Backslash character in your `PATH` output was considered literal, not escaping for space.

You need:

```
PATH="/Applications/Racket v6.2/bin:$PATH"; export PATH
```

or:

```
PATH=/Applications/Racket\ v6.2/bin:$PATH; export PATH
```